# Having timeout after setting up proxychains

Tags: linux, networking, proxy

I've installed ProxyChains on my linux machine and I'm trying to hide my IP over the internet. I went on one of those sites that gives you a list of ips, in this case, `proxylist.hidemyass.com` and got a random IP just for test: 201.172.63.150:63034. On my `proxychains.conf` I addeed at [ProxyList] the following as instructed:

> socks4 201.172.63.150 63034

Afther that, I ran on terminal `proxychains iceweasel` to try to browse behind this Ip but I can't access any site. Through terminal output of iceweasel I see many lines like:

> |DNS-request| ipleak.net 
>   |S-chain|-<>-201.172.63.150:63034-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<--timeout
>   |DNS-response|: ipleak.net does not exist

So, two questions. Am I setting it up correctly? And if so, why am I having this timeout? Thanks in advance.